# Script for appending a string to all files in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line

I'm new to Linux. I need a little script that appends "\n exit" to the end of all files in `/test`.

I tried `echo "\n exit" > file1.sql` it worked but `\n` (the new line) didn't work.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Using `echo -e` as @mklement0 suggests, your script is simply:

```
for i in test/* ; do 
      echo -e '\n exit '  >> "$i" 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `echo $'\n'" exit"`.

`$'\n'` is a literal newline in bash.

Another option is to use `echo -e`, which turns on interpretation of escape sequences such as `\n`:

```
echo -e '\n exit'
```

Also, since you mention *appending*, you probably want `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: that's a cool little trick! I would just expand with a for loop: for f in $(ls); do  echo $'\n'"exit" >> $f ; done

Comment: @speeves: Nice, but using globbing (`for f in *`) is more robust (and faster) than command substitution (`for f in $(ls)`); I also suggest double-quoting `$f` - @damienfrancois's answer does all that.

Answer (score 1):

Two common solutions not yet mentioned:

```
printf '\n exit\n' >> file

echo '
 exit' >> file
```

(Each of the above puts a newline after the "exit", if you don't want that, use:

```
printf '\n exit' >> file
```